# How to change wordpress news root url

Tags: htaccess

I have a site and my customer has decided the url for what used to be news should now be renamed to tips-and-tricks, but we want to keep the old urls too because we don't want to lose old links. I've tried several .htaccess settings but that's really not my field of expertise, and I'm not even sure if this is the right way to achieve this with WordPress.

So, for example:

```
site.com/news
```

should become

```
site/tips-and-tricks
```

but /news should point to /tips-and-tricks as well. Can I do this and what is the best way to do it with WordPress?

Comment: is wp installed in news directory or on root of domain?

Comment: In root, the entire site is wp. I just want my post overview to be on something else than /news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin create a page with slug tips-and-tricks. Than go to Settings->Reading than in first section set up your new page to be your posts page. WP will handle proper redirection of old permalinks to new.

Comment: Pfff, that's so obvious... Thanks, that worked, of course!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it, but you could try plugin from this article: http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/advanced-permalinks/.
Good luck

Comment: I've seen that plugin but unfortunately it doesn't allow you to simply rename news/ to something else, tips-and-tricks/ as I need it.